# Is this definition of a dependency property with a generic owner class incorrect?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, designer

I have a custom generic user control that I wish to have a content property named as `AdditionalContent`. The cut down implementation with all non error specific code removed is.

```
[ContentProperty("AdditionalContent")]
public class WgReactiveUserControl<TViewModel> : UserControl
        where TViewModel : class
{
        public UIElement AdditionalContent
        {
            get { return ( UIElement ) GetValue(AdditionalContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AdditionalContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AdditionalContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty
              .Register("AdditionalContent", 
                          typeof(UIElement),                       
                          typeof(WgReactiveUserControl<TViewModel>),
              new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

and I get the following error in the designer.

[image]

which refers to this code.

[image]

plain text code is

```
<w:MeasuredViewportLayoutHelpPanelBase 
         x:Class="Weingartner.EyeshotExtensions.MeasuredViewportLayoutHelpPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:w="clr-namespace:Weingartner.EyeshotExtensions"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance w:MeasuredViewportLayoutHelpPanelModel, d:IsDesignTimeCreatable=false}">


    <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#C0333333" BorderBrush="#C0D4D4D4" Margin="20">

    </Border>

</w:MeasuredViewportLayoutHelpPanelBase>
```

with code behind being

```
public class MeasuredViewportLayoutHelpPanelModel 
{ }

public class MeasuredViewportLayoutHelpPanelBase 
  : WgReactiveUserControl<MeasuredViewportLayoutHelpPanelModel>
{ }

public partial class MeasuredViewportLayoutHelpPanel 
  : MeasuredViewportLayoutHelpPanelBase
{
}
```

I can't figure out what might be wrong with the declaration of the dependency property `AdditionalContent` that will cause the designer to give this error.

Comment: Seems like a bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245734/wpf-usercontrol-initializecomponent-exception

Comment: It's likely that the generic type `<TViewModel>` is screwing things up.

Comment: Does this error occur in runtime or only in the designer?

Comment: It's only in the designer.